# How to get the return value of a java-script function to a variable which is called on keyup

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I am really new to javascript. I am trying to create an auto load text box for my project. I want to get the return value of a javascript function to a variable when the function is called on keyup event. How can I do that.

```
   <input id="autocomplete" onkeyup="myFunction()"> 

    <script>

    var abc = "";    
    function myFunction() {
      var keywordx = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
      abc = keywordx;
    }



      console.log(abc);// abc should have the typed values in the 

    </ script>



**EDITED
```

Comment: your `console.log(abc)` can be done inside `myFunction()`. Why do you want the value outside.

Comment: yep. But I want to use the value of "abc" variable outside the function.

Comment: But why? tell the purpose? the way you are using it, it will print `""`.

Comment: for the time being I used console.log(abc); but I need it to use as an input another function.

Comment: You can use it somewhere else, you just have to make sure that that code doesn't run until after you finish typing.

Comment: so call that function inside `myFunction` like `functionCall(abc)`.

Comment: The problem in your question is that you're running `console.log()` when the page loads, not after the user types.

Comment: Why not `...onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)" ...` or `... onkeyup="abc = this.value"...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input id="autocomplete" onkeyup="myFunction()" onchange="showIt()"> 

function showIt() {
    console.log(abc);
}
```

This waits until you finish editing the field before trying to use `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<input id="autocomplete" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<input type='button' id='temp' onclick='getText()' value='Get Text'>
<script>
    var abc = "";

    function myFunction() {
        var keywordx = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
        abc = keywordx;
    }

    function getText() {
        console.log(abc);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should fix your problem. There's not a need to create the variables outside the function. Just keep it simple by passing around one variable as the value and resetting it with each onkeyup event.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("autocompleted").value;
    console.log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution will be like this

```js
var autocomplete = document.querySelector('#autocomplete');
autocomplete.onkeyup = function(e) {
  alert(e.target.value);
  //e.target.value is value of input
  //console.log or use it
}
```

```html
<input id="autocomplete">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use Hidden Filed instead of global variable.

You can achieve the same functionality using jQuery

```
<input id="autocomplete" onkeyup="myFunction()"> 
<input type="hidden" id="someFlag" />
<script>
    $('#autocomplete').keyup(function () {
        $('#someFlag').val($('#autocomplete').val());
        console.log($('#someFlag').val());
    })
</script>
```